British tv comedy skit show where an actor plays a blackface vagabond
Maybe you can help me name a British skit show that I saw an episode or two of on Netflix a while back where in one skit a white man in blackface plays some sort of vodoo vagabond that talks jibberish and works his way into the front door of a nervous woman's house (played by a male actor).  It was supposed to be funny but was pretty surreal and creepy.  Seems like it was made recently in the 2000s or late 90s at the oldest.
The setup seemed to be about a small town in the english boonies.

Surreal and creepy British comedy makes me think of The League of Gentlemen http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0184135/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2 , but I can't remember them doing blackface.

It is The League of Gentlemen, the character is Papa Lazarou
clip here



